# Why do sap.m.Input fields in my sap.m.Table not come into focus when I switch from one to the other?

Tags: sapui5

I have an sap.m.Table control which has rows which contain some sap.m.Input controls. These input controls are bound to values in the table's model data. When I put my cursor on one of the input fields and type a value and then immediately put the cursor on an input field in another row, the focus is shifted to the top of the table rather than on the input field I just clicked. I then removed the binding to the value on the input fields and it worked properly. How can I make this work by keeping the binding on the input fields?